# Consigo fazer com que o documento gerado no código VBA abaixo seja salvo na pasta do arquivo fonte ou que ele peça para salvar em um local especifico?

Tags: vba, pdf

Estou criando uma macro no Excel que seleciona um texto e cola em outra aba da planilha e gera um .pdf automaticamente.

Quero tentar fazer com que o usuário em outro computado salve esse arquivo ou no mesmo caminho em que a planilha fonte vai está ou então apareça para ele a opção de salvar. (gostaria da primeira opção pois se só tiver a segunda como opção ele terá que fazer isso repetidamente.

Consigo fazer com que o documento gerado no código VBA abaixo seja salvo na pasta do arquivo fonte ou que ele peça para salvar em um local especifico?

```
Sub imprimirAG2P()
'
' imprimirAG2P Macro
' imprimir AG 2P
'

'
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AG1 2P"
    Sheets("MEC - 111 - AGITATOR").Select
    Range("G7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AG1 2P"
    Range("G8").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "D:\00 - MEUS DOCUMENTOS\DOCUMENTOS\01 - DOC CONTROL\01 - FVI - FVM\01 - FVI\03 - FVI PRONTAS\FVI\AG1 2P.pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Sheets("databank").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri aqui que se eu tirar o "Caminho" do arquivo como por exemplo "D:\OUTRO HD" e deixar só o nome do arquivo: AG1 2P.pdf, ele automaticamente salva no "C:\user\fulano\Documents"

```
´´´
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "AG1 2P.pdf" _ 
´´´
```

Isso não resolve totalmente o problema mas já ajuda.

Agora só resta saber se consigo fazer com que o documento seja salvo na pasta do arquivo fonte ou que ele peça para salvar em um local especifico.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Marcus!

Pra atender a sua opção basta usar a propriedade **ActiveWorkbook.Path**, que é o atributo que diz onde a planilha está salva (partindo da premissa que não é um arquivo ainda não salvo)

Então:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        Activeworkbook.path & "\AG1 2P.pdf" _
```

Se quiser entregar ao usuário um prompt você usa:

```
Dim f As Object
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

f.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
f.AllowMultiSelect = False
f.Show

MsgBox f.SelectedItems(1)
```

A diferença é que você vai ter que tratar um pouco o que vai aparecer, pra se proteger de seleção vazia ( if f.SelectedItems(1) <> "" then...) e etc

Mas a lógica geral é essa